# Why does the panel only appear if I setVisible(false) first?

Tags: java, swing

If I click on the 'include' menu item it shows the panel, but only if I `setVisible(false)` first, if I remove that line it stops working.

In the `ActionListener` I'm for the `menuItem` I'm creating a new Panel with a label inside, but this label will only show on the screen if after instantiating it I call `setVisible(false)` first.

#### MainWindow.java

```java
package main;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
    MainWindow() {
        super("Carros");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout((null));
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JMenuBar jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
        jMenuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 606, 21);
        this.getContentPane().add(jMenuBar);

        JMenu carMenu = new JMenu("Carros");
        jMenuBar.add(carMenu);

        JMenuItem includeMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Incluir");
        carMenu.add(includeMenuItem);

        includeMenuItem.addActionListener(e -> showIncludePanel());
    }

    private void showIncludePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setVisible(false);
        panel.setBounds(5, 20, 431, 241);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Primeiro panel");
        panel.add(label);
        panel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### Main.java

```java
package main;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `this.getContentPane().setLayout((null)); getContentPane().setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) `jMenuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 606, 21);` Instead use ..

Comment: .. [`JFrame.setJMenuBar(JMenuBar)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setJMenuBar(javax.swing.JMenuBar)). 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 4) The effect of `showIncludePanel()` could be achieved by adding the panel and a blank label at start-up and setting the text of the label when needed. This would also be more reliable than adding the panel & label dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `this.pack()` on the frame after adding the new component.

Also, the frame allows you to set a "J" (Swing) menu bar. Avoid using AWT as much as possible... at least do not mix it with Swing components as it is an older heavy-weight library.

I tweaked the flow of the program to make is more maintainable and readable.

#### MainWindow.java

```java
package q60816855;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    public MainWindow() {
        super("Carros");
        this.setLayout(null); // Same as calling null on the content pane

        createMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createMenu() {
        JMenuBar jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu carMenu = new JMenu("Carros");
        jMenuBar.add(carMenu);

        JMenuItem includeMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Incluir");
        carMenu.add(includeMenuItem);

        this.setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);

        System.out.println(this.getContentPane().getPreferredSize());

        includeMenuItem.addActionListener(e -> {
            this.getContentPane().add(createIncludePanel());
            this.pack();
        });
    }

    private JPanel createIncludePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Primeiro panel");

        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBounds(20, 20, 431, 241);
        panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        return panel;
    }
}
```

#### Main.java

```java
package q60816855;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MainWindow());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer by any means but rather a potential answer. It's **possible** that because you're using a **null layout** for the content pane that the component hasn't been validated. Try and vall window.validate() or window.invalidate() after creating the window to see if that works.